# removing a character in a certain context (using shell script)

Tags: text-processing, command-line, regular-expression

So, I have a file with a list of names, like

```
Thomas Newbury
Calvin Lewis
E. J. Frederickson
Lamar Wojcik
J.C. Lily
Lillian Thomas
```

And I'm eventually going to try and split these into a long list of first and last names, but before I do that, I want to turn "E. J." into "E.J." and I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that with bash.

I know `"[A-Z]+. [A-Z]+."` matches "E. J." but I don't know what command allows me to remove a space only in the context of being between two dotted letters?

Comment: do you *really* want to do this *in bash*, or *from bash* with a text editor (such as sed/awk/etc)?

Comment: Ah! I didn't know that was confusing. It appears I mean 'from bash'. Updated for clarity :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do with GNU `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/^([A-Z]+\.)[[:blank:]]([A-Z]+\.)/\1\2/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I think sed is your best bet, here is my version:

```
sed -r ':a;s/^(.*\.)(\ )+(.\.)(.*)$/\1\3\4/;t a' file

-r -- use extended regular expressions
:a -- label "a" 
^(.*\\.) -- 1st group matches any character "." from the line beginning up to a literal "\\.".   
(\ )+ -- 2nd group matches white space (+ is one or more) 
(.\.) -- 3rd group matches the next letter 
(.*)$ -- 4th group matches to the end of the line
;t a -- if the previous substitution did something then branch to label "a"
/\1\2\4/ -- replaces the matches with groups 1,3,4 removing the space
```

This handles arbitrary abbreviations, e.g.: S. O. V. Sovereign